# Is it possible to check the process id of child in different pid namespace?

Tags: linux, process, namespace

Is it possible to find the PID of the child process which is in a separate PID namespace?

I am able to get the child process PID with respect to the parent namespace but I need to find the PID of the child with respect to separate PID namespace where the child is currently running.

I am able to get PID from a child via IPC, but is there any way to find it without child process help?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Given the PID of a process, the information of all the PID namespaces it belongs to is available from a [proc entry](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/stable/linux.git/tree/Documentation/filesystems/proc.rst?h=v5.10#n252) in `/proc/PID/status`:

> ```
>  NStgid                      descendant namespace thread group ID hierarchy
> ```

Or from [`man proc`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/proc.5.html):

> NStgid : Thread group ID (i.e., PID) in each of the PID namespaces of
> which [pid] is a member. The leftmost entry shows the value with
> respect to the **PID namespace of the reading process**, followed by **the
> value in successively nested inner namespaces**. (Since Linux 4.1.)

I don't know if there's any other method than using `/proc` to retrieve this information.

---

Here's an example with a sleep process that was started in a LXC-within-a-LXC container so will have two nested PIDs (aka tgids) when read from the initial PID namespace:

```
# pidof sleep
443701
# grep ^NStgid: /proc/443701/status 
NStgid: 443701  685 170
```

So its PID is 685 in the intermediate namespace and 170 in the final namespace: this process sees itself as having a PID of value 170.

The last entry is how the process sees itself.

If a parent process spawned a child process in an other PID namespace without using the newer `clone3(2)` system call, it will exist only in one additional PID namespace anyway, and its pid there will be the 3rd and last entry in the line (counting `NStgid:` as first entry). If doing checks by entering those PID namespaces (using `nsenter(1)`or `setns(2)`), care must be taken to also create a new dummy mount namespace (with `unshare(1)`, `unshare(2)` or `clone(2)`) and mount again `/proc` there, or `/proc` entries will still reflect the parent PID namespace's values and won't appear to change.

Further examples following above. Check that's the sleep command:

```
# nsenter -t 443701 -p unshare -m --mount-proc ls -l /proc/170/exe   
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 0 Dec 21 23:03 /proc/170/exe -> /bin/sleep
```

Having a PID reference in the intermediate PID namespace (the intermediate LXC container is named *stretch-amd64*) will allow to know how it's seen from there:

```
# lxc-info -Hp -n stretch-amd64
442977
# nsenter -t 442977 -p unshare -m --mount-proc grep ^NStgid: /proc/685/status
NStgid: 685 170
```

Answer (score 0):

A process can have many children. The best way to get a child PID is to get it when the child is created. Both `fork` and `clone` return child PID on success.

Comment: Yeah, but `fork` and `clone` returns the PID of the child with respect to the parent namespace. let say a parent is in `ns1` namespace and the child is spawned in `ns2` namespace (via `CLONE_NEWPID`). now child process PID is 1 because it is the first process in the `ns2` namespace. how to get the child process PID as 1 from the parent process?

Comment: So, is it not `1`?

Comment: No, PID returned to the parent by `clone` or `fork` will be the PID of child process with respect to namespace where parent is running.

Comment: If `fork` or `clone` returned PID as 1 then If again parent spawns the other children in another namespace say `ns3`, It will also has PID as 1. Which makes PID collision so, linux will not do that.

Comment: Sorry there is something very fundamental that I am missing. Only I know not what it is.

Comment: thanks for taking the time to help 